# Why js do not push inject variables?

Tags: javascript

```
var abcd = [];
var id =3;
var cor = 4;
var relatX = 102.67498779296875;
var relatY = 75.73751831054688;
abcd.push({id : {cor: {relatX, relatY}}});
```

---

**Take:**

```
[{"id":{"cor":{"relatX":102.67498779296875,"relatY":75.73751831054688}}}]
```

---

**I need**

```
[{"3":{"4":{102.67498779296875,102.67498779296875}}}]
```

Comment: Your inner object `{102.67498779296875,102.67498779296875}` isn't valid. Objects are key/value-pairs. If you only want values use an array. `[relatX, relatY]` results in `[102.67498779296875,102.67498779296875]`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

```
var abcd = [];
var id =3;
var cor = 4;
var relatX = 102.67498779296875;
var relatY = 75.73751831054688;
abcd.push({[id] : {[cor]: {relatX, relatY}}});
```